# Reading File 2 chars at a time

Tags: c#

Hello I want to Read only 2 characters from file at a time

can any body help me how to do that ?

next time when I read, I must have to read next two characters and so on until file ends.

please help

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/94223t4d.aspx

Comment: Why not read the entire file content into a string and then operate on the string (fetch 2 characters from string), thus you will decrease number of I/O operations and it would be faster

Comment: `File.ReadAllText("filename").Select((obj, index) => new { obj, index }).GroupBy(o => o.index / 2).Select(g => new string(g.Select(a => a.obj).ToArray()));`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [StreamReader.ReadBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readblock.aspx) method to do this.

Pass the method a two-character length array, tell it to start writing at index 0 and to read two characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824.aspx) or a [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx) in conjunction with any other `Stream`, here I use `FileStream` and a `StreamReader`:

```
int currentPosition = 0L;

using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[2];

        sr.Read(buffer, currentPosition, 2);

        // buffer now contains the first 2 characters in the file, use a loop or similar to read the rest of the file
    }
}
```